# Proxmox LVM on ISCSI resize

Tags: lvm, iscsi, proxmox, san

I have a cluster of 5 nodes running Proxmox PVE 5.1.
I had configured a ISCSI storage connected to a SAN and several LVM mapped to LUNs.
I resized one of these LUNs, but the LVM is still the old size.
Can I make a pvresize to extend the LVM without danger ?
Here is (part of) my configuration :
**/etc/pve/storage.cfg**

```
iscsi: iscsi_proxmox
portal 172.31.52.1
target iqn.1984-05.com.dell:powervault.md3600i.6f01faf000d898fa0000000052a24fce
content none

lvm: VG_VM3_PROXMOX
vgname VG_VM3_PROXMOX
base iscsi_proxmox:0.0.1.scsi-36f01faf000d898fa000063e859ba83ce
content images,rootdir
shared 1
```

**multipath -ll**

```
LUN_VM3_PROXMOX (36f01faf000d898fa000063e859ba83ce) dm-8 DELL,MD36xxi
size=1000G features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=14 status=active
  |- 11:0:0:1  sdd  8:48   active ready running
  `- 14:0:0:1  sdaf 65:240 active ready running
```

**pvdisplay**

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/LUN_VM3_PROXMOX
  VG Name               VG_VM3_PROXMOX
  PV Size               500.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              127999
  Free PE               14591
  Allocated PE          113408
  PV UUID               rQTf7i-3uzI-zBC7-Hl3G-6ubH-g8Oe-trr1uw
```

Regards,

Comment: which lvm volume are you actually trying to resize?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/